# declaring jsx element as a global variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello is there a way to declare react component globally so that when I render the same component the values are persisted, I am aware the redux or some other state management lib can be used, but for the time being I want to use this option cuz I'm in the middle of the project. For example

```
constructor() {
    this.accountInfoJSX = <AccountInformation ref={(sender) => {
        this.accountInformationMod = sender;
    }} />;
}
```

I can try to save the element in the global variable but each time when the render is called it initializes a new instance.

Edit:
yes sure. i have this method. I have 2 buttons on screen based on which i render different components. User can made some changes on each component, so i am trying to to use same component so that the changes made in component are persisted. i have tried returning this.accountInfoJSX as well as this.accountInformationMod not its not working. On former it re render the new component and values are lost and on latter it show nothing on screen.

```
get getCurrentScreen() {
    if (this.state.selectedScreen == Screens.accountInformation) {
      return this.accountInformationMod;
    } else if (this.state.selectedScreen == Screens.myInformation) {
      return <MyInformation />;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide more informations about your use case?

Comment: Look you can obviously keep react component object in localstorage or sessionstorage, but i have never seen some one doing it. Look this example https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/98648/ Persist value for each component instead of persisting the component itself

Comment: In native swift or java we can have global component like Buttons, TextFields and there state is maintained since they are on global scope. I thought may be a similar approach can be used in react native. In react native i m not sure we have a localstorage or session storage